# Would a tips on verifying languages be on topic?

Tags: discussion

I thought it would be helpful to have a question with tips on demonstrating that a system fits our definition of a language.  I feel that it would be helpful for language writers to have a section for tips to reference, however I don't know if this would be considered on topic on the main.

Thoughts?  Would such a question be on topic or even helpful?

Comment: I think verifying the definition of a language is moot now given [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10426/20260)?